# Ways to get maximum size of a queue through JMS

Tags: jms, spring-jms

I am using Spring and have 2 MQQueues. I need to check the maximum capacity using only JMS. In other words lets say someone configured 1 MQQueue to have maximum capacity of 4000 message, I need to be able to check that configuration.

Is it possible only using JMS or must I have direct access to MQQueues and use MQQueue java libraries?

Comment: I would guess it's a proprietary property and not available over the JMS standard APIs.

Comment: @GaryRussell fair enough thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JMS API doesn't define any administrative methods to check configuration details like the maximum capacity of a queue. Therefore, you'll need to use a proprietary method to retrieve this information.

Comment: so if I am understandsting correctly I need to go through MQQueue library ?

Comment: I don't see any methods on the [MQQueue object](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQQueue.html) to get the maximum capacity so I believe you'll need to use some other administrative operation to get that information.